# How to fill multiple values into One Column in pandas dataframe? (without using strings) Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, multiple-columns

so far I managed to do this by using a string and splitting it up later.

```
print(df)

       a    b    c   z
0      0    0    0   "23,8,100"
1      1    1    1   "23,2,100"
2      2    2    2    "1,8,100"
3      3    3    3   "23,5,300"
4      4    4    4     "23,8,7"

# converting column to list
x_list = df["z"].tolist()

# splitting via list comprehension
[[float(x) for x in xstring.split(",")]  for xstring  in  xlist]
```

But I wonder if there is a faster way to put a small **list** [23,8,100] into one single column and receiving a **list** back when calling the index in dataframe.
(or even better: calling the whole column as a list of lists)

(the amount of elements in the list depends on a static input, 
so when i have 3 elements it will alway be lists of 3, 
but i could also enter 100, so the amount of elements in every list will be 100.)

Comment: kindly post ur expected output, or what u r after

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to convert string to list
First, remove extra `"` quotes using `strip` then split string into list

```py
df.z.str.strip('"').str.split(',')
0    [23, 8, 100]
1    [23, 2, 100]
2     [1, 8, 100]
3    [23, 5, 300]
4      [23, 8, 7]
Name: z, dtype: object
```

And use `map` to convert string to `float` with `apply`

```py
df.z.str.strip('"').str.split(',').apply(lambda x:list(map(float,x)))
0    [23.0, 8.0, 100.0]
1    [23.0, 2.0, 100.0]
2     [1.0, 8.0, 100.0]
3    [23.0, 5.0, 300.0]
4      [23.0, 8.0, 7.0]
Name: z, dtype: object
```

or you can assign back

```py
df.z = df.z.str.strip('"').str.split(',').apply(lambda x:list(map(float,x)))
```